# Why doesn't Rails 2.3 generate a Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2, gemfile

Recently I started my adventure with Ruby on Rails using version 2.3.14. When generating a new project, why isn't Rails creating a `Gemfile`?

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: AFAIK all recent versions do.

Comment: I'll also point out this is an X/Y problem. If you're just starting to explore Rails, don't start out with a legacy version. Use Rails 3 unless you're inheriting a legacy code base.

Answer (score 2):

#### Rails 2.3 Doesn't Have Bundler Support

Why? Because it just doesn't. [Rails 3 has native Bundler support](http://gembundler.com/rails3.html), but you can [add Bundler support to Rails 2.3](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html) by following the step-by-step directions on the Bundler web site.

#### Roll Your Own

If you just want a Gemfile, rather than Bundler integration with Rails, you can create one easily enough.

```
gem install bundler
bundle init
```

#### Vendor Your Gems

In older versions of Rails, the way to handle gems was to vendor your gems. The old 2.3 version of [A Guide to The Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/command_line.html#rake-is-ruby-make) may help you, especially the section that covers `rake gems:install`.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 2.3 doesn't have built-in bundler support because it came out before Bundler.

The [Bundler website](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/rails23.html) provides instructions for adding Bundler to Rails 2.3.

In short:

- Add a `config/preinitializer.rb` to set up the bundled environment before Rails is loaded
- Update your `config/boot.rb` to require the bundled gems
- Move any `config.gem` declarations to the `Gemfile`
- Proceed as usual